# How to keep android device's layout responsive

Tags: android, xml

I am new to xml and android and I was designing a simple application that has 3 buttons in two rows. Now I can't get to a way to make the layout responsive (adjust according to the screen resolution) for every android device. I did a little search but couldn't find anything relative.
    So my first question is can you create a UI with xml that works with all sizes of screen?
    If yes then how to do it? Or at-least please point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: Android usually handles scaling. What is happening that is a problem? Could you include the xml you are using?

Comment: For simple view you can use LinearLayout with weight. UI will be adjusted for all devices.

Comment: Make multiple layouts for different screen sizes, such as `layout-sw600dp` folder (For 7 inch tablet), and placing the same XML with different layouts inside.

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992754/ui-design-tips-and-tutorials-for-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user Radhe has suggested, `android:layout_weight` used appropriately within a `LinearLayout` will easily scale the buttons. If you have the buttons lined up horizontally within a `LinearLayout`, set each button's height to whatever you'd like (I prefer `match_parent`) and set each button's width to `0px`. For each button, you may set a `layout_weight`. The weight of each button represents the ratio of the width of each button to every other within that `LinearLayout`. So if you have 3 buttons, each with a width of 1, the will all be the same width. If one button has a width of 2 and the other two have a width of 1 each, the one with the width of 2 will be as wide as the other two combined. Just play around with it until you get what you like.